# Calculating the difference bwteen dates in a specificed date range

Tags: sql-server, date, casting, range

I'm trying to calculate the days between two dates for rows than faly within two dates only.

Essentially if a record falls in the financial year '2012-11-01 00:00' AND '2013-10-31 23:59' I want to know how many nights there are between B.Depart and the end of that year, ie '2013-10-31 23:59'.

The error I get is:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data
>   type int.

This is what I have got to:

```
 CASE 
 WHEN B.Depart BETWEEN '2012-11-01 00:00' AND '2013-10-31 23:59' THEN datediff (minute, B.Depart, '2013-10-31 23:59')
 ELSE 'NULL' 
 END AS '2012/13 nights'
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Change 'Null' to Null?

Comment: Doh! Thnaks, also change 'minute' to 'day' to get my days

Answer (score 0):

```
 CASE 
 WHEN B.Depart BETWEEN '2012-11-01 00:00' AND '2013-10-31 23:59' THEN datediff (minute, B.Depart, '2013-10-31 23:59')
 ELSE NULL
 END AS '2012/13 nights'
```

Instead of 'NULL' which would be treated as varchar, go for NULL.

Answer (score 0):

So your query was:

```
 CASE 
 WHEN B.Depart BETWEEN '2012-11-01 00:00' AND '2013-10-31 23:59' THEN datediff (day, B.Depart, '2013-10-31 23:59')
 ELSE NULL 
 END AS '2012/13 nights'
```